# How to stop saving rtsp streaming video in android by using FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am saving a rtsp stream by using FFMPEG in android. When i forcibly stop saving video the video file is corrupted. Is there any command to stop  saving rtsp stream video. I am using [ffmpeg](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library.

Here is the command which i use to save streaming video-

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy-hhmmss");
String file_path = path + "/recording" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".mp4";
String[] cmd = {"-y", "-i", "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-strict", "-2", "-s", "720*1280", "-aspect", "16:9", file_path };
execFFmpegBinary(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not interrupt mp4 format directly so you should change your format to mkv. so your file path should look like this:

```
String file_path = path + "/recording" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".mkv";
```

But if you really want to go with mp4 only in that case you should add this extra settings in your cmd: `-movflags +empty_moov+separate_moof`